# Undefined .env variables when webpack goes into production mode

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, dotenv

I'm using the dot-env NPM package in order to pass simple variables to my webpack/express application.

When I run in PRODUCTION mode for webpack, all my variables from .env become undefined.

I'm building up a development and production webpack config files and currently have the following setup.

Any advise on the mistakes I'm making and why my .env variables are being dropped would be greatly appreciated.

- package.json (Scripts)

  ```
   "buildDev": "rm -rf dist && webpack --mode development --config webpack.server.config.js && webpack --mode development --config webpack.dev.config.js",

    "buildProd": "rm -rf dist && webpack --mode production --config webpack.server.config.js && webpack --mode production --config webpack.prod.config.js",
  ```
- webpack.dev

  ```
  const path = require("path");
  const webpack = require("webpack");
  const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
  const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
  const paths = require("./config/paths");
  const isDevelopment = false;
  const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

  require('dotenv').config()
  module.exports = {
    entry: {
      main: [
       "webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000",
       paths.appIndexJs,
     ],
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
      publicPath: "/",
      filename: "[name].js",
    },
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    mode: "production",
    target: "web",
    devtool: "#source-map",
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          enforce: "pre",
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "eslint-loader",
          options: {
            emitWarning: true,
            failOnError: false,
            failOnWarning: false,
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          include: path.resolve(paths.appSrc),
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
        {
        // Loads the javacript into html template provided.
        // Entry point is set below in HtmlWebPackPlugin in Plugins
          test: /\.html$/,
          include: path.resolve(paths.appSrc),
          use: [
            {  
              loader: "html-loader",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          include: path.resolve(paths.appSrc),
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          include: /node_modules/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/,
          use: ["file-loader"],
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        favicon: "./src/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico",
        template: "./src/html/index.html",
        filename: "./index.html",
        excludeChunks: ["server"],
     }),
     new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
     new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
     new Dotenv()
   ],
  };
  ```
- webpack.prod

  ```
  const path = require("path");
  const webpack = require("webpack");
  const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
  const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
  const paths = require("./config/paths");
  const isDevelopment = false;
  const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

  require('dotenv').config()
  module.exports = {
    entry: {
      main: [
       "webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000",
       paths.appIndexJs,
     ],
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
      publicPath: "/",
      filename: "[name].js",
    },
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    mode: "production",
    target: "web",
    devtool: "#source-map",
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          enforce: "pre",
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "eslint-loader",
          options: {
            emitWarning: true,
            failOnError: false,
            failOnWarning: false,
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          include: path.resolve(paths.appSrc),
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
        {
          // Loads the javacript into html template provided.
          // Entry point is set below in HtmlWebPackPlugin in Plugins
          test: /\.html$/,
          include: path.resolve(paths.appSrc),
          use: [
            {
              loader: "html-loader",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          include: path.resolve(paths.appSrc),
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          include: /node_modules/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
        },
      /*{
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: { url: false, sourceMap: true } },
            { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } 
            },                    
          ]
         },*/
       /*{
           test: /\.css$/,
           include: path.resolve(paths.appSrc),
           use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
         },
         {
           test: /\.sass$/,
           use: [
             MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
             { loader: 'css-loader', options: { url: false, sourceMap: true } },
             { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },                    
           ]
         },
         {
           test: /\.css$/,
           include: /node_modules/,
           loader: [
             isDevelopment ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
               {
                 loader: "css-loader",
                 options: {
                    modules: true,
                    sourceMap: isDevelopment,
                 },
               },
            ],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(scss)$/,                
            use: [
              MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, { loader: 'css-loader', 
                options: { url: false, sourceMap: 
                true } }, { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },                    
            ]
          },*/
          {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/,
            //include: path.resolve(paths.appSrc),
            use: ["file-loader"],
          },
        ],
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': { 'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') }
        }),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
          favicon: "./src/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico",
          template: "./src/html/index.html",
          filename: "./index.html",
          excludeChunks: ["server"],
        }),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new Dotenv()
     ],
  };
  ```
- webpack.server

  ```
  const path = require("path");
  const webpack = require("webpack");
  const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
  const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

  module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    const SERVER_PATH =
      argv.mode === "production" ? "./src/server/server-prod.js" : "./src/server/server-dev.js";

   return {
     entry: {
      server: SERVER_PATH,
     },
     output: {
       path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
       publicPath: "/",
       filename: "[name].js",
     },
     mode: argv.mode,
     target: "node",
     node: {
       // Need this when working with express, otherwise the build fails
       __dirname: false, // if you don't put this is, __dirname
       __filename: false, // and __filename return blank or /
     },
     externals: [nodeExternals()], // Need this to avoid error when working with Express
     devServer: {
       historyApiFallback: true,
     },
     module: {
      rules: [
        {
          // Transpiles ES6-8 into ES5
     test: /\.js$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     use: {
       loader: "babel-loader",
     },
   }
   ],
   },
  };
  };
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at yow webpack.prod in its plugins section you have it like.
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
'process.env': { 'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') }
So basically you is setting process.env to be equals to What Eva is there

## solution

first you need to install two modules

- **dotenv-expand**
- **dotenv**

```sh
$ npm i -D dotenv-expand dotenv
```

### Next

create a new file called `env.js`, I mean the name is up to you. Place the file same place where yow webpacks are

#### env.js

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const {NODE_ENV} = process.env.NODE_ENV;

const dotenvFile = `.env.${NODE_ENV}`;

require('dotenv-expand')(
      require('dotenv').config({
        path: dotenvFile,
      }));
  

const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
process.env.NODE_PATH = (process.env.NODE_PATH || '')
  .split(path.delimiter)
  .filter(folder => folder && !path.isAbsolute(folder))
  .map(folder => path.resolve(appDirectory, folder))
  .join(path.delimiter);

// set your own prefix
const PREFIX = /^ENETO_/i;

function getEnvironment() {
  const raw = Object.keys(process.env)
    .filter(key => PREFIX.test(key))
    .reduce(
      (env, key) => {
        env[key] = process.env[key];

        return env;
      },
      {
        NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
        PORT: process.env.PORT||3000,
      }
    );
  const stringified = {
    'process.env': Object.keys(raw).reduce((env, key) => {
      env[key] = JSON.stringify(raw[key]);
      return env;
    }, {}),
  };

  console.log("stringified", stringified);

  return { raw, stringified };
}

module.exports = getEnvironment();
```

##### NOTE

Make sure to add a prefix so all of them shuld start with a `PREFIX`
you can set your own prefix

now on each one of yow webpacks add it;

#### webpack.server.js

```js
/**
 webpack server
*/
"use strict";

const path = require("path");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const webpack = require("webpack");
/**
 * HERE IS IMPORTED ALL THE WAY TO THE BOTTOM YOU'LL SEE IT
 */
const vars = require("./env");
const { NODE_ENV } = process.env;

const entry = [path.join(__dirname, NODE_ENV === "production" ? `../src/prod.ts` : `../src/dev.ts`)];
module.exports = {
    target: "node",
    name: "server",
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    entry: [
        require.resolve("@babel/register"),
        require.resolve("core-js/proposals"),
        require.resolve("core-js"),
        require.resolve("@babel/runtime-corejs3/regenerator"),
        require.resolve("es6-promise/auto"),
        ...entry,
    ],
    devtool: false,
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    output: {
        filename: "[name]-bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: "[name].chunk.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../bundle"),
        publicPath: "/",
        libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
                exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
                loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
                options: {
                    babelrc: false,
                    configFile: false,
                    compact: false,
                    presets: [[require.resolve("@babel/preset-env")]],
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    cacheCompression: false,
                    sourceMaps: false,
                    inputSourceMap: false,
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin(vars.stringified)],
};
```

Do the same with yow client and thats it :3

Comment: Thanks Ernest. But even with removing that line it still unsets everything. I'm investigating further as to what the root cause is. I've updated my questions to include the webpack.server file.

Answer (score 0):

do not need third part deps.
just use `env` like this:

`--node-env=`

```js
// in package.json 
"build": "webpack --node-env=production --config build/webpack.config.js"
```

or

```js
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const isDevelopment = argv.mode !== 'production';
  return {
    // Config...
  }
}
```

see:

- [`--node-env`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/pull/4537#issue-800296057)
- [`argv`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6460#issuecomment-364286147)